# Custom wpdb query - how to sort post by another table meta_count

Tags: custom-field

Custom wpdb query code below works well but I need sort by

> **stt2_meta** table **meta_count**

,

```
 <?php
     $querystr = "
        SELECT ID, post_title FROM $wpdb->posts
                    WHERE post_type = 'post'
                        AND post_status = 'publish'
                        AND ID IN ( SELECT post_id FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."stt2_meta )
                    ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 10;";
     $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

    ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $querystr = "SELECT {$wpdb->posts}.ID,
                     {$wpdb->posts}.post_title,
                     {$wpdb->prefix}stt2_meta.meta_count
        FROM {$wpdb->posts}, {$wpdb->prefix}stt2_meta
        WHERE {$wpdb->posts}.post_type = 'post'
          AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_status = 'publish'
          AND {$wpdb->posts}.ID IN ( SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}stt2_meta )
        ORDER BY {$wpdb->prefix}stt2_meta.meta_count DESC
        LIMIT 10;";
 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but It returns an empty page. No debug information available.

Comment: The query looks fine. I would start by running the generated query directly via phpmyadmin & checking the results or doing `var_dump()` on nearby code to get some other information